# dompdf: how to remove borders from the rendered table in pdf?

Tags: html, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm having some issues in displaying a table with dompdf:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/domPdfTable.png

The table contains all borders I don't have in my original table in html:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/htmltable.png

how can I remove these borders from the final pdf document ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following in your stylesheet:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

-or-

```
table { border-spacing: 0px; }
```

-or-

```
table { border-style: outset; }
```

When you use the border attribute DOMPDF separates the cell borders per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders). However, DOMPDF appears to differ from most web browser by not supplying a surrounding border on the table. Using one of these style declarations will allow DOMPDF to more closely approximate the web browser.

Comment: also discussed here: http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf/browse_thread/thread/2c7f9e40ce6c949e